Nginx Server doesn't forward requests to Flask-Container in Docker on Amazon EC2
I try to use Nginx and Flask running in Docker Containers on a Amazon EC2 Instance, but there seems to be an issue with communication between my two containers. The Nginx server doesn't forward requests to the Flask app.
I use docker-compose like this:
`version: '3'

services:
  flask-app:
    build: 
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "5000:5000"
    networks:
      - app-network
    volumes:
      - ./data:/app/data

  webserver:
    image: nginx:alpine
    volumes:
      - ./html:/usr/share/nginx/html
      - ./nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf:ro
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    networks:
      - app-network
    depends_on:
      - flask-app

networks:
  app-network:
    driver: bridge`

And I have this configuration added to nginx.conf:
 server {
        listen 80;

        resolver 127.0.0.11  ipv6=off;

        server_name flask-app;

        location / {

            root /usr/share/nginx/html;
            index index.html;
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
        }

        location /predict {
            proxy_pass http://flask-app:5000/predict;

            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;

            proxy_intercept_errors on;

            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Range';
            add_header 'Access-Control-Expose-Headers' 'Content-Length,Content-Range';

            if ($request_method = 'OPTIONS') {
                return 204;
            }

        }
    }

My Flask-App looks like this:
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify
import joblib
from flask_cors import CORS
from query_recommender import queryReco

app = Flask(__name__)
CORS(app, resources={r"/predict": {"origins": "*"}})


@app.route("/")
def home():
    return "Hello, Flask!"


@app.route("/predict", methods=["POST"])
def predict():
    try:
       etc.....

I have a website, where I try to use fetch in Javascript like this:
fetch("http://flask-app:5000/predict", {....
But this doesn't work!
It works when I use the IP of the EC2 Instance like this:
fetch("http://123.123.123.123:5000/predict", {....
But unfortunately this doesn't work when I use the container name "flask-app" instead.
I can ping flask-app from inside of my webserver container, so I assume the resolver is working.
What am I doing wrong?
I tried various configurations of nginx.

The error is specifically calling fetch() from a browser-based application?  The browser isn't running in a container and can't use Docker networking features.  "Unknown host" error calling containerized backend from frontend describes this case further.  If you already have the reverse proxy, just fetch("/predict") without specifying a host name.

JavaScript Fetch URL: The URL you're using in your JavaScript fetch call, http://flask-app:5000/predict, will not work from the client's browser because flask-app is not a recognizable domain outside of your Docker network. The browser will not be able to resolve flask-app to the correct IP address. Instead, you should use the public DNS or IP of your EC2 instance, like http://123.123.123.123/predict. Make sure that you expose the correct port (80 in the case of your NGINX setup) and not the Flask app port (5000) directly to the public.

Thank you! Yes 123.123.123.123/predict works.
fetch("/predict") doesn't work. I think I have to check my nginx configuration why this doesn't work.

"Unknown host" error calling containerized backend from frontend fixed it for me. Like in the Github-Repository I now use a separate Container for the nginx reverse proxy. That worked for me.
